# Trouble creating a comma-separated output string using variables

Tags: vba

I am trying to create a string output where each of the variables are quoted and separated by a comma. This is the code I'm trying to use.

```
objOutputFile7.WriteLine(""& strCodeSetName & "'","'" & strCreateID & "'","'" & strSiteCode & "'","'" & strSiteName & "'","'" & strSiteName &"'",""false",,,,"false"")
```

I've been bouncing between 2 different errors. One that tells me a cannot use parentheses while calling a Sub. The other stating it's expecting a close-parentheses inside one of the variable names.

I've looked through online resources and could not find a close example. Could someone help me resolve my conundrum?

Comment: Would help to show a sample of the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to know exactly what output you expect/want, but maybe something like this?

```
objOutputFile7.WriteLine "'" & strCodeSetName & "','" & _
          strCreateID & "','" & strSiteCode & "','" & _
          strSiteName & "','" & strSiteName & "',false,,,,false"
```

Comment: This comes so VERY close! The output is in single quotes. I need them in double.

Comment: We might get closer if (as requested above) - you gave us *a sample of the output you expect*.

Comment: For double quotes, replace every`'` above with `""`

Comment: This comes so VERY close! I added the last section as a variable enclosing the outside of the value in treble-quotes. """

Converting the output file to `"" & strCodeSetName & ",""" & strCreateID & """,""" & strSiteCode & """,""" & strSiteName & """,""" & strSiteName & """," & strLastSec` got me where I needed to be

Thank you for the push!

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is using the `Join` function. You have to create an array with all your variables...

```
Dim outLine as String
Dim myValues as Variant
myValues = Array(strCodeSetName, strCreateID, strSiteCode, _
                 strSiteName, strSiteName, "false,,,,false")
outLine = Join(myValues, ",")
objOutputFile7.WriteLine outLine
```

Comment: Or maybe `outLine = "'" & Join(myValues, "','") & "',false,,,,false"` after removing the false from the array.